# How to use special pronoun?

Tags: nouns, neologisms

I want to use some special pronoun. For example, the "have-nots" means who have nothing.

If I am trying to say "the ___ want to earn more by working hard", should I use "want" or "wants"? I just want to figure out how does verb works, if I use self-created word.

Answer (score 3):

On the analogy of *haves and have-nots* you would use *wants*.

Be careful, however. This construction is not "productive", so the coinage will only make sense if you introduce it in the company of its contrary, *want-nots* before you use it by itself. If you don't make it clear that you are relying on analogy with an established use, readers will take you to be using *wants* in its ordinary sense as a noun, the things which one desires or lacks.

Also, you should avoid saying *The wants want to earn more*; it is very poor style to use a word twice in different senses that close together, except for obvious (and successful) humorous effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **haves** and **have-nots** as **groups** of people, the noun could be replaced by **they**

> The **haves** want to earn more
>   **They** want to earn more

if you are referring to a specific **have** person

> **That** *(particular)* ***have*** **wants** to earn more
>   (S)he **wants** to earn more

but this sounds awkward. The rule follows the same verb usage for singular and plural subjects.